# PDF Viewer Part - Access Denied

Tags: 2013, web-part, access-denied, pdf

Having an issue with a PDF viewer web part on our SharePoint 2013 server. Regardless of the user level or browser, it will give an "Access Denied" error.

The strange thing about this is that we have a VM with SharePoint on the server (purely for testing content before we add it to the live site) which opens them completely fine. From what I can see, the central administration settings are also all the same, and the PDF is stored in a document library within SharePoint which everyone has the correct rights to see.

Opening the PDF manually is completely fine, and we're running Adobe Acrobat XI.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What PDF Viewer Web Part are you using? I have been working on a SharePoint 2013 site at work and don't have one called that specifically so I use the Content Editor Web Part instead.

This may or may not work for the issue but I'll explain it either way.

Go to edit mode on the desired page.

Go to Insert, Web Part, scroll to Media and Content, select Content Editor and click add.

The Web Part should display like so:

[image]

After this click the web part and edit it.

The Web Part should display "Click here to add new content".

Click on this and it should highlight like a text box.

[image]

Once you are here within that text box, click edit source within the "Format Text" ribbon above.

Insert this code:

Be sure to insert the link to your pdf document at: src="(here)" .

Once you do all this and hit okay the PDF should display on the page.

Hopefully that helps? This might help if it's some error with the Web Part you're using.